# How do I pass the level 7 "will find forward" puzzle?

Tags: vim-adventures

The objective is to delete all the red outlined characters. 
It allows only 12 key presses and you enter from the bridge above (on either <kbd>n</kbd>, <kbd>d</kbd> or the space after "find)". Leaving the puzzle resets it.

Map:
[image: will find forward map]

Available keys: 
[image: available keys]

Comment: Could you clarify what the goal is? I know VIM well enough that I might be able to answer, but I'm not sure exactly you're supposed to do; are you just highlighting the `x`s or do you want to actually visit them with the cursor?

Comment: Ok I went and did level 1 to get an idea of how this thing works.  IIUC you have to use `x` on the highlighted red characters, and delete all of them in 12 keystrokes.  Are you allowed to use `:s` commands?  Otherwise the keys you have available are insufficient - I don't seen any way to do it in 12 keys.  You need to go find `f` and `;`, I presume.  If not those some other possibilities are `/`, `n`, `t`, and `,`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From the game author:

> In order to finish this puzzle, you need to collect the '**f**', '**;**' and
>   '**,**' keys.  Note that when you **bump into bushes**, you sometimes find
>   things - either keyboard shortcuts or people.
>
> You should **go back to the Alice text at the beginning of the level**
>   (the long one) and **go through all the bushes**. There are a lot of
>   things to find. It will also make traversing the text a lot easier.
>
> One more thing, if you're still missing one keystroke to finish this
>   text after you collect everything, **remember that ';' and ',' repeat
>   the last search within the line**, even if it was not performed on the
>   current text.
>
> Hope that helps.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Ohhhh I see - so the problem is, the original asker just hasn't found all the keystrokes he needs to solve the puzzle.

Comment: Performing the initial search on another text helped me getting rid of one key stroke that I had too much.

Comment: Thanks! I also had one too many and couldn't find my way around it. Excellent!

Comment: can you give exact key stroke you did? I'm already using `;` and `,` and Im 1 keystroke short to finish it

Comment: @CharlieParker: The missing keystroke is your initial Fx.
You have to enter the riddle, press Fx, escape the riddle and re-enter it. On your next try you only need ";", "," and "x". Don't use the F anymore.
Enter the riddle twice is forced. You cannot solve it on your first try.

Answer (score 17):

If you type the `fx` before enter in the keystroke-counting text, you only need to use `j` and `;` to solve the puzzle.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by this? I keep missing 1 keystroke to finish this level.

Comment: Go up to the `emptyStr` line, enter the line, and type `fx`. When you return to the `f will find forward` block, you can then use `,`, `;`, `j` and `x` to solve the puzzle.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.